# Swift - Convert [[String:Any?]] to Data

Tags: json, swift

I have an `[[String:Any]]` object populated like:

`var result : [[String : Any]] = [[String : Any]]()`

And I need convert it to `Data`.

I'm just using: 
`JSONEncoder().encode(result)`
To convert it.

But I get this error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Exist a simple way to convert a `[[String:Any?]] object to`Data` ?

Comment: `JSONEncoder` doesn't support `Any`. Use `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: `let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:result options:[])`? with a catch to see if there is an issue.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`JSONEncoder` can only encode objects whose type conforms to `Encodable`. If you want to encode `Any` to JSON, you need to use `JSONSerialization` to do that.

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:result)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also using **struct** for that and using

```
let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(struct_Object))
```